# Filemaker Pro 12 - Applescript - Object not found 1728

Tags: applescript, filemaker

Edit: More info - Filemaker Pro 12, Mac OSX Mavericks. Also: I have put the global variables on the layout to make sure that they are getting set properly, and I have checked the folder to make sure the file exists.

I have a filemaker script with native applescript that stopped working after some time.  The script is triggered when clicking on a photo in a filemaker container and causes the photo to open in preview.  The error is Object Not Found - Unknown Error 1728

```
tell application "Filemaker Pro"
   activate
tell window "Deals_Platform"
go to layout "Equipment Detail"
set photoPath to (get data of cell "_global_photo_path" of layout "Equipment Detail"    of current record)
set photoFolder to (get data of cell "_global_photo_folder" of layout "Equipment Detail" of current record)
end tell
end tell
tell application "Finder"
activate

open folder photoFolder of folder "PRODUCTS_PHOTOS" of folder "CONTACT" of folder "Files" of folder "Customer Database" of folder "Business Files" of folder "PhD Assets" of folder "J Files" of folder "Documents" of folder "J" of folder "Users" of startup disk


open document file photoPath of folder photoFolder of folder "PRODUCTS_PHOTOS" of folder "CONTACT" of folder "Files" of folder "Customer Database" of folder "Business Files" of folder "PhD Assets" of folder "J Files" of folder "Documents" of folder "J" of folder "Users" of startup disk

close folder photoFolder of folder "PRODUCTS_PHOTOS" of folder "CONTACT" of folder "Files" of folder "Customer Database" of folder "Business Files" of folder "PhD Assets" of folder "J Files" of folder "Documents" of folder "J" of folder "Users" of startup disk



end tell
```

Old Script (this does not work either)

```
  tell application "FileMaker Pro"
activate
set photoPath to (get data of cell "_global_photo_path" of current record)
set photoFolder to (get data of cell "_global_photo_folder" of current record)
  end tell
tell application "Finder"
activate
open document file photoPath of folder photoFolder of folder "PRODUCTS_PHOTOS" of folder "CONTACT" of folder "Files" of folder "Customer Database" of folder "Business Files" of folder "PhD Assets" of folder "J Files" of folder "Documents" of folder "J" of folder "Users" of startup disk
end tell
```

Comment: are you trying to run the script while in layout mode ? I don't think the script can access data of the cell while in layout mode

Comment: Nope, I am only running the script from browse mode.

Comment: can you explain this then "It seems to stop working when I switch from browse to layout mode."

Comment: I am not sure how it stopped working.  Today I went back in Time-Machine and found a file that does still work.  The script is different and I copied the old script into my newer file and it didnt help.  The reason the script is different on the new file is because I was trying to solve the error. I will try to get the old file to break too, but I haven't been able to yet. See above for the old script

Comment: Just to be clear, the script has not started working again since it last broke.

Comment: Hey mcgrailm: I got it to work by putting the 3 fields: global_photo_path, global_photo_folder and photo_folder_name on the actual layout.  It must have something to do with the applescript needing to see those on the layout when it grabs them.  Thank you very much for taking the time to try and help me, I am a complete beginner...

Comment: yes anytime you need to access a field either in applescript or filemaker calculation it must exist on the layout

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but mcgrailm, FileMaker definitely does not require fields to be on the current layout—nor any layout, actually—for a calculation to reference them. It would need to be on the layout in order for a **Go to Field** or **Go to Object** script step to work, but that’s just common sense: you can’t select something that isn’t there.